# How to add views to multiple layouts in the main activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

how to add views programmatically to linear layouts in my activity_main layout.
I have so far tried the below code. I am a beginner so I don't know what's wrong with my code.
pixelGrid.java is a class used here for drawing. It's a custom view class.

```
//MainActivity.java
package com.shahroze.myworld;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LinearLayout controlpanel;
LinearLayout simulation;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       controlpanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.controlLayout);
       simulation = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.simulationLayout);

       Drawresult();



   }
   protected void Drawresult() {

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //how to add views to simulation and control panel
       simulation.addView(new pixelGrid(this));//this line makes the app crash.
       


   }
```

Comment: `simulation` is null because you call `findViewById()` before calling `setContentView()`

Comment: Make a Common Activity for Common View and Extends All Activities from Common Activity.

Comment: To make Ben's comment clearer, call ```setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);``` right after super.onCreate **and** before other initializations.

Comment: Okay. Now it works. @Ben P. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout inflater for adding views programatically in your layout.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater